What makes 'What are functions of Instruction Register in Assembly language' a question asking to explain code?
I was reading What are functions of Instruction Register in Assembly language?. It was very quickly closed and down-voted as being off-topic, presumably because the author was asking to explain code. After reading the question, I'm not so sure this is an "explain the code" question. To me, the question focuses on the function or purpose of the Instruction Register in Assembly. This feels more like a conceptual question about the language.
While perusing the programming-language tag, I'm seeing questions that are not too different than what the question above is asking. This also might be due to my complete lack of knowledge about the Assembly language.
What makes the question above about explaining code?

I am tempted to vote to reopen. I voted to reopen the question. I'm sorry, but I think this first-time poster has asked a good question. I also up-voted.

I agree. I think this question is about the assembly language, or CPU machine op-code design, instead of certain lines of code. Therefore, the current judge Questions asking for assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code, or using coding tools should be inaccurate.

this part of the question starting with "T1 : MAR <- IR (address)" is plagiarized (quoted without attribution) from https://www.codershelpline.com/courses/theorypapers/computer-organization/instruction-cycle/

@gnat: ok, so we ask the OP to put a link to their source. Haven't you ever copied and pasted code from the Internet?

@GregBurghardt not only code, text is copied as well. No matter how you twist is, plagiarism is not allowed at Stack Exchange

I think it's pretty clear that the material is not the original work of the author, since the question is entirely to ask what it all means.

Let me add this for people who don't have enough rep to see deleted content, in case you are wondering what has happened to the subject: the question in stake was closed and deleted by two site moderators because of plagiarism. According to them, just adding a link to the original source would not have solved the issue.
